# Typescript & React: Passing props between components vs default props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am fairly new to Typescript and creating a React app with Typescript. I'm having a bit of trouble passing props from one component to another. I've included an example below, my issue is around default props for components.

When I call my child component in my parent component, I get an error:

`Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'IProps': className, disabled ts(2739)`

I thought that because I have default props on my child component, they would fill in for any missing props when calling the component from other components.

I know I can make individual props optional in the interface `IProps` in my child component using `className?: string` but this is not a solution I'm looking for as it presents more problems than it solves.

I'd prefer not to have to note each default prop when I call a child from another component like below as for some components, I have many props:
`<Child class={''} disabled={false} />`

I'm sure there's a fairly simple solution for this but I can't find any direction so far. Any advice or direction would be welcome.

```
// Parent component: 

import React, { FC } from 'react'

import Child from './child'

const Parent: FC = () => {
    return (
        <Child />
    )
}

export default Parent


// Child component: 

import React, { FC } from 'react'

interface IProps {
  className: string
  disabled: boolean
}

const Child: FC<IProps> = ({ className, disabled }: IProps) => {
  return (
    <button className={className} disabled={disabled}>
      Click here
    </button>
  )
}

Child.defaultProps = {
  className: '',
  disabled: false,
}

export default Child
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved it, for anyone looking at this answer: just need to pass in the default props into the component as well as any props as per code below:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'

interface IProps {
  className: string
  disabled: boolean
}

const Child: FC<IProps & Child.defaultProps> = ({ className, disabled }: IProps) => {
  return (
    <button className={className} disabled={disabled}>
      Click here
    </button>
  )
}

Child.defaultProps = {
  className: '',
  disabled: false,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide default arguments to stop this happening:

```
const Child: FC<IProps> = ({ className = 'foo', disabled = false }: IProps) => {
  ...
}
```

This should actually get around the optional props problem you have, especially if you use these default arguments (i.e., lazy devs not checking what props are required/optional). Now you can make them optional ...

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that and doesn't work unfortunately. I think the issue is when the component is instantiated in the parent component, it sees the props are required and doesn't check the default props either in arguments or further down in the `Child.defaultProps`

Comment: If you modify the interface to make both props optional does that happen @paulosullivan22 ?

Comment: Making the props optional in the interface does solve the error but I am looking to avoid this as it presents a lot of issues when using the props in the body of the component

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/react-typescript-and-defaultprops-dilemma-ca7f81c661c7

Answer (score -3):

You did right but missed to pass className and disabled props the child component.

const Parent: FC = () => {
return (

)
}

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a chat