# When passing a React functional Component as a parameter of a function, how should I declare the function parameter type with TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I have a issue with type declaration for function parameters. Please see the code below,

```
const FunctionalComponent = ({propA,propB}: FunctionalComponentProps): JSX.Element => {
   return 
}
```

Now I want to pass the FunctionalComponent as a parameter to another function. How should I declare the parameter type?

```
const Foo = (
   para1: string,
   TheFunctionalComponent: ??? // Tried React.FC<any>, it work, want to provide more strict such as React.FC<FunctionalComponentProps>, this way it does not work. Is the React.FC<any> the only way? 
)
```

Comment: Take a look at the answer from this post, this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58093669/typescript-react-passing-props-between-components-vs-default-props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this example:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

export interface ChildComponentProps {
  name: string;
  id: string;
}

export const ChildComponent = ({ name, id }: ChildComponentProps): JSX.Element => (
  <div>
    Hi {name} my id is {id}
  </div>
);


const ParentComponent: FC<{ Comp: FC<ChildComponentProps> }> = ({ Comp }) =>
  <Comp name={"2"} id={"3"} />

const App = <ParentComponent Comp={ChildComponent} />
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQFDNIAekscwAdjEijl0SOIQAWwADYATQtUi8k-AApUwAZ1zM4cXihBIAXHA0wofAOYBuHTxkmzF3jeYlWHLvDQReZsZKy8uC+yvAAvHAAFHj6htjAMqQmEtJyCqGq6hoAlCYAUgDKABoAdACiUkiG-HDhAHzRdgA8MsAAbvV2ugASwLhxSGQgAJ72PFo4ie66zQD0bZ3MObasPn7wKigM-MGKYSZEzXh7h4TNqUEZSlkQmo0kjZExYgqkOXVds3t6BkjhOAARAAmQFkRIAwEAZjBcDmXWY638AEEwGA6nBmlsdjA9pl4HsAZd0iEbjAyPCgA)

You should also provide a type of your `ParentComponent`

**UPDATE**

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

export interface ChildComponentProps {
  name: string;
  id: string;
}

export const ChildComponent = ({ name, id }: ChildComponentProps): JSX.Element => (
  <div>
    Hi {name} my id is {id}
  </div>
);


const ParentComponent = (Comp: FC<ChildComponentProps>) =>
  <Comp name={"2"} id={"3"} />

const App = ParentComponent(ChildComponent)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQFDNIAekscwAdjEijl0SOIQAWwADYATQtUi8k-AApUwAZ1zM4cXihBIAXHA0wofAOYBuHTxkmzF3jeYlWHLvDQReZsZKy8uC%20yvAAvHAAFHj6htjAMqQmEtJyCqGq6hoAlCYAUgDKABoAdACiUkiG-HDhAHzRdgA8MsAAbvV2ugASwLhxSGQgAJ72PFo4ie66zQD0bZ3MObasPn7wKigM-MGKYXXReyZEzalBGUpZEJr1OXVds3t6BkjhOABEAEwfZInvHwAzL84HMusx1v4AIJgMCHLY7GB7TIwKLndIhK4wHJAA)

More generic approach:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

export interface ChildComponentProps {
  name: string;
  id: string;
}

export const ChildComponent = ({ name, id }: ChildComponentProps): JSX.Element => (
  <div>
    Hi {name} my id is {id}
  </div>
);


const ParentComponent = <Props,>(Comp: FC<Props>) =>
  (props: Props) => <Comp {...props} />

const App = ParentComponent(ChildComponent)({ name: 'John', id: '#1' })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQFDNIAekscwAdjEijl0SOIQAWwADYATQtUi8k-AApUwAZ1zM4cXihBIAXHA0wofAOYBuHTxkmzF3jeYlWHLvDQReZsZKy8uC%20yvAAvHAAFHj6htjAMqQmEtJyCqGq6hoAlCYAUgDKABoAdACiUkiG-HDhAHzRdgA8MsAAbvV2ugASwLhxSGQgAJ72PFo4ie66zQD0bZ3MObasPn7wKigM-MGKYXVwzWoQmpj1UXsmRMfZ9Tl1XbpRYNkmJ5oPDUd7uKX-r1OGjIcy6zHW-gAgmAwIctjsYHtMjBLoF0iElPwcjE9AZjHR8hBxLxaAkHHQAMQARlopByQA)

Comment: Thank you mate, it looks like the correct answer, but a little bit different. The function to accept the component is a function, not a functional component. So we cannot use the props form like {Comp}, I think that is where the issue comes

Comment: @EvenZhi I don't understand. COuld you please provide more context?

Comment: The use case of the Parent Function is const a = ParentFunction(a,b,WithComponent). It does not pass parameters into a props object like how component do, so we cannot declare a type WithComponent, then declare the ParentComponent like ({Comp}:WithComponent) . I am not sure if you understand

Comment: Normally we use a Component like <FunctionalComponent propa ={}> . That will have a props object. However, it is different this time. I have to use the FunctionalComponent this way: const a = FunctionalComponent(propa). Therefore, the way to declare the prop type of FunctionalComponent will be different.

Comment: COuld you please provide an example with expected an unexpected errors? I m a bit confused

Comment: Hi @captain-yossarian , Please see the sandbox below.  https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-hermann-1clfw?file=/src/ParentComponent.tsx

Comment: I really appreciate your time. However, it still not working, as I mentioned, I have to use ParentFunction this way,  const App = ParentFunction(ChildComponent)

Comment: @EvenZhi made another one update.

Comment: Hi @captain-yossarian , now you almost got my condition, the reason I pass a ChildComponent is that I have to pass different ChildComponent to the ParentComponent in different conditions, and the props of those ChildComponents are different, let say, ChildComponentB = ({name,id, otherOption}) => (return something). Then how should I define the ParentComponent Prop, as you know, ParentComponent(Comp: FC<ChildComponent>), the 'Comp' is just a name, which means it can be any Component. The thing make the whole system hard is different Components have different props

Comment: @EvenZhi smth like this https://tsplay.dev/mx5nBW ?

Comment: Hi, in order to make it more clear, I added some more codes over there, I am not familiar with the way <Props,>(Comp: FC<Props>). Could you please give me a little more explanation, or if possible. Could you please finish the ParentComponent parameter declaration according to my snippet? Again, really appreciate your patient and nice explanation.

Comment: @EvenZhi where you made an update?

Comment: In the link you send me, or if you cannot find the link, I will copy the change to my link list as well. https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-hermann-1clfw?file=/src/ParentComponent.tsx